# Problems with Aruco library on Debian 9.5 - OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, debian

I am trying to detect Aruco markers through my camera using OpenCV for Python 2.7 on Debian 9.5, but I can't run my code because of an errore dealing with `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers()`. Running it on Windows, it does not have any problem. In particular, I wrote in my code:

```
cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image=gray, dictionary=aruco_dict, parameters=parameters, 
                         cameraMatrix=camera_matrix, distCoeff=camera_distortion)
```

where `camera_matrix` and `camera_distortion` are respectively the camera matrix and the camera distortion parameters I got by camera calibration.

More precisely, the error says that there's no `cameraMatrix` input parameter for the function `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers`. How do I fix this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your error is due to your `opencv` version. Check it with:

```
 cv2.__version__
```

Older versions of `opencv` (such as 3.2.0, that is maybe your default version for Debian 9) do not have `cameraMatrix` or `distCoeff` as input parameters of `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` function.

If you are interested in getting newer versions of `opencv` for your OS (such as 4.1.0.25), you have to do:

```
sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
```

If you are not, just remove `cameraMatrix` and `distCoeff` from your inputs, it would run anyway.